# How to Redirecting old .html page to new wordpress pages

Tags: redirect, http-redirect

I have purchased a new domain with old pages and links. To captilize on the previously made links I have created some pages with similar and updated content.
The problem I am facing is with the redirections.
The old website was static and made with html. So every previous link has .html in the url.
The wordpress plugin "Redirection" is unable to redirect them.

Can I put a redirection on indivisual pages?
Example. /page1017.html redirect to catagory/xyz in wordpress

I have tried to solve it with the redirection plugin